# How to replace urls using regex php

Tags: php, regex

i have a text file in which i have many urls like this `http://96.156.138.108/i/01/00382/gbixtksl4n0p0000.jpg#xywh=0,0,108,60`

i want to change all urls with my urls like this `http://testing.to/testing/vtt/vt1.vtt#xywh=0,0,108,60`

i am using this regex

```
$result = preg_replace('"\b(https?://\S+)"', 'http://testing.to/testing/vtt/vt1.vtt', $result);
```

but its not working good its change whole url

from this `http://96.156.138.108/i/01/00382/gbixtksl4n0p0000.jpg#xywh=0,0,108,60`

to this `http://testing.to/testing/vtt/vt1.vtt`

i want to change only url except **#xywh==0,0,108,60** like this

> http://testing.to/testing/vtt/vt1.vtt#xywh==0,0,108,60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[^\s#]` instead of `\S` to match only non-spaces, non-`#` characters:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '"\bhttps?://[^\s#]+"',
    'http://testing.to/testing/vtt/vt1.vtt',
    $result
);
```

Comment: i also want to get old url `http://96.156.138.108/i/01/00382/gbixtksl4n0p0000.jpg` from file into my variable what should i do

Comment: @ZealSol, Use the same pattern with [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-match.php): `preg_match('"\bhttps?://[^\s#]+"', $result, $matches); print_r($matches);`

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$sourcestring="http://96.156.138.108/i/01/00382/gbixtksl4n0p0000.jpg#xywh=0,0,108,60";
echo preg_replace('/https?:\/\/.*?#/is','http://testing.to/testing/vtt/vt1.vtt#',$sourcestring);
```

Comment: `http?` should be `https?`.

Comment: Correct it should be `https?` ... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although `preg_replace` is good and all, there is a built in function for parsing urls,
namely [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$url = 'http://96.156.138.108/i/01/00382/gbixtksl4n0p0000.jpg#xywh=0,0,108,60';

$components = parse_url($url);

print_r($components);

$fixed = 'http://testing.to/testing/vtt/vt1.vtt#' . $components['fragment'];

print $fixed . PHP_EOL;
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => 96.156.138.108
    [path] => /i/01/00382/gbixtksl4n0p0000.jpg
    [fragment] => xywh=0,0,108,60
)

http://testing.to/testing/vtt/vt1.vtt#xywh=0,0,108,60
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with simple explode() function

```
$url = "http://96.156.138.108/i/01/00382/gbixtksl4n0p0000.jpg#xywh=0,0,108,60";

$urlParts = explode("=", $url);

$newUrl = "http://testing.to/testing/vtt/vt1.vtt#xywh=";

$newUrl += $urlParts[1];
```

Comment: Considering `xywh` could be changed: `$urlParts = explode("#", $url); $newUrl = "http://testing.to/testing/vtt/vt1.vtt#";`

Answer (score 0):

```
$re = "/(.*)#(.*)/"; 
$str = "http://96.156.138.108/i/01/00382/gbixtksl4n0p0000.jpg#xywh=0,0,108,60"; 
$subst = "http://testing.to/testing/vtt/vt1.vtt#$2"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

OR

```
$re = "/(http?:.*)#(.*)/"; 
$str = "http://96.156.138.108/i/01/00382/gbixtksl4n0p0000.jpg#xywh=0,0,108,60"; 
$subst = "http://testing.to/testing/vtt/vt1.vtt#$2"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```